# How to convert strings in arrays to ISO Latin-1

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to build up a HTML report based on values from a spreadsheet like this:

---

```
Ereigniszeilen += EreignisVorlage 
          .replace("<ZeileNr>", BerichtZaehler)
          .replace("<KindName>", AlleEintraege[j][ColumnNameKind-1])
          .replace("<LeistungsArt>", LeistungsArt)
          .replace("<Datum>", DatumLeistung)
          .replace("<CheckIn>", CheckIn)
          .replace("<CheckOut>", CheckOut)
          .replace("<TotalStunden>", TotalStunden)
          .replace("<Bemerkung>", AlleEintraege[j][ColumnBemerkung-1]);


var AttachmentInhalt = AttachmentVorlage.replace("<EVENTS>", Ereigniszeilen);
var AttachmentInhalt = AttachmentVorlage
   .replace("<BerichtsDatum>", BerichtsDatumFormatiert)
   .replace("<EVENTS>", Ereigniszeilen); 

var Bericht = [{fileName:"Bericht-Rapport.html", content: AttachmentInhalt}]
```

---

And then send by email:

---

```
MailApp.sendEmail("heinz.ruffieux@tfv-lac.org", TitelMitKind, "", //Versand des Emails
          {htmlBody: "Guten Tag liebe Eltern,<br> Bonjour chers Parents, <br><br> \
          Beiliegend senden wir Ihnen den wöchentlichen Bericht für die Betreuungsleistungen für <b>" 
          +KindName +" von " +StartDatumFormatiert +" bis " +EndDatumFormatiert +"</b>.<br><br> \
          Nous vous envoyons ci-desous le rapport heptomadaire sur les services d'accueil du <b>" 
          +KindName + " du " +StartDatumFormatiert +" au " +EndDatumFormatiert +".</b><br><br>\
          Mit freundlichen Grüssen <br> \
          Meilleurs salutations <br><br> \
          Tagesfamilienverein des Seebezirks <br> \
          Association d'accueil familial de jour du district du Lac <br><br>" +ZusatztextDeutsch +"<br>" 
          +ZusatztextFranz, attachments: Bericht});
```

---

The result is a simple mail with some text and the report as a HTML attachment. This email is addressed to Swiss users only.

In principle everything works great since several months, but I do have some problems with char coding. The spreadsheed (source) contains German and French special characters which do not display correctly. 
Especially on iPhones and apparently some Windows IE9 systems. On my own Linux system with Chrome and Firefox everything just looks great.

The HTML Body text of the email above however display correctly on every system so far.

Can anybody help me how to apply the correct character set in Google Apps Script?

Many thanks

Heinz

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in HTML but I guess that you should build a header in your html body to tell the browser (or the email client app.) to use the right character set. You could do that easily by sending to yourself the same message manually on gmail (of with your favorite mail client app) and analyse the html content of the message to see how it's done ?

just a suggestion ;-)

EDIT : (another suggestion ;-)  If the problem occurs in the attachment, why not converting it in pdf ?
there is a built in converter in the DocsList service.

```
   var docN = 'docname';
   var ID = 'ID you have get prior to this'
   var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(ID).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
   var attach = {fileName: docN+".pdf",content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};
   MailApp.sendEmail('email@xxx.com', 'Your document as PDF ('+docN+')', 'see attachment', {attachments:[attach]});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I tried that one without success... I read somewhere that a header does not help, as long as the content of the database - in this case a spreadsheet - is still in another format....

Any other ideas?? I cannot be the only one having this problem, can I?

Thanks.
Heinz

Comment: While re-reading your question I'm not so sure I understood exactly where the problem occurs... is it in the attachment? what type of document is it actually?  I thought it was in the email's body but I guess I was wrong ...could you set me on the right track please ? (btw, I noticed that there are some spelling errors in the french part of the message, this is out of subject but since I'm french speaking I just see it ;-)

Comment: Hi Serge, sorry I missed your updates:

Yes the problem is with the attachment. Converting into a PDF would be THE idea. However I do not even save the attachment in the docs list, so I guess I cannot use the converter.

Comment: The coding of the Email body is fine but not in the attachment. Based on the snipplets above, I filling up some Spreadsheet records into an HTML file which I then bring into an HTML file (var Bericht = [{fileName:"Bericht-Rapport.html", content: AttachmentInhalt}]) and then send by email as an attachment.

Your questions however raised a whole other question: Whe the heck do I even generate an HTML file???
I now used the exact same procedure but include the HTML table directly into the email body - AND THIS WORKS!!

THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR ASKING THOSE QUESTIONS!

Best regards

Heinz

Comment: Well I'm happy it helped, even if it was 'by accident' ;-)